# Pyspark filter dataframe by a comparison between date and string datatype

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in pyspark with the following construction:

`DataFrame[Urlaubdate: string, Vacationdate: date, Datensatz: string, Jobname: string]`

Now, I would like to filter the dataframe by comparing vacationdate with urlaubdate, unfortunately they have different datatypes. I would like to get filter the rows where vacationdate is bigger than Urlaubdate.
Do you have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you would have to use user-defined functions as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

def compare(urlaubdate, vacationdate):
    # do your comparison here (cast types if necessary)
    # return True or False

# define a udf out of your function
compare_udf = udf(compare, BooleanType())

# filter your dataframe based on it
df_filtered = df.filter(compare_udf(df.urlaubdate, df.vacationdate))
```